# Command line application shoogle requires python3 but Ubuntu 16 defaults to python 2.7

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, command-line, ubuntu-16.04, default

The command line application shoogle (https://github.com/tokland/shoogle) which exposes google api services at a terminal command line requires python3 but the ubuntu 16 default python is 2.7.

I have tried alias and calling the shoogle app from subprocess in a python3 shell but (of course) the os still provides the default. I have been reluctant to make system wide changes to .bashrc or PYTHONPATH e.g. as so many other resource expect 2.7. But I am currently using this on a virtual machine so if it does break I can recover. That seems the only option but impractical in a production environment.

I've found very little shoogle help online (the author suggests SO etc. for support) so if any one has any experience with shoogle or suggestions to get the requiured python version I'd be happy to hear.

Running shoogle from a python3 interpreter finds the 2.7 files:

```
3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
Python Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

from subprocess import call

call (['shoogle', 'show'])

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/bin/shoogle", line 11, in <module>
import shoogle

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/shoogle/__init__.py", line 5, 
in <module> from .shoogle import *

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/shoogle/shoogle.py", line 14, in <module>
from . import commands

 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/shoogle/commands/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from . import execute
```

Comment: how are you lauching Python?  Have you tried just typing `python3`?

Comment: when you are in python type `import sys`, the type `print(sys.version)` and tell me what you see

Comment: @SurestTexas  import sys
print(sys.version)
3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

Comment: @SurestTexas just to reiterate the the app (shoogle) dosen't run as a python3 module but as terminal commmand. I tried it in the python3 shell to try to trick it into using the python3 environment.

Comment: I understand that, but what command are you using to run it in the terminal??

Comment: Although I really do think you are invoking the Python 2.7 interpreter as being the root problem here; you ___Could___ try using a virtual environment instead: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/
I use python 2 and 3 on my computer with no library "mixing" problems like you seem to have.  However, it is easy to get the wrong interpreter running (you think it is 3 but you are really in 2, etc).

Comment: @SurestTexas, thanks. the command and argument is - "shoogle show" e.g. I will look into the virtual environment suggestion. I was beginning to wonder how this utility could be used at all and did not know about virtualenvs or did not make the connection so thanks again

Comment: OK... I think I might be overusing this comment section now, but after Looking at your error output again, it looks like you installed shoogle using `pip` and you did not use pip3 (to install to the python3 directories).  `pip` will, but default install to the default python.  I think you must use pip3 or find the pip located in the python3 folder and run that pip instead when installing...  Your shoogle got installed in this path: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`.  Using a virtenv is one way to avoid these mistakes

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked. Thanks for being patient.

Comment: @SurestTexas, if you make that answer I can vote it up or whatever else I should do.

Comment: Did you use pip3 or a virtual environment?  I don't know enough about virtual environments to give a quality answer.  However, I believe you can craft an answer to your own question based on what you found, and then "accept" that answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @Surest Texans suggestions I uninstalled the shoogle app and used pip3 install to reinstall. Now the application works as expected when called from the command line.